# Why can I read int values from file in C++ but not float?

Tags: c++, file-handling

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Create a dynamic array to hold the values
    vector<int> integers;
    //Create a dynamic array to hold the values
    vector<double> floating;
    int x;
    double d;
    int sum1=0;
    double sum2=0.0;
    string line;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("data.txt", ios::in);

    while(infile >> x)
    {
        integers.push_back(x);

    }
    while(infile >> d)
    {
        floating.push_back(d);

    }
    int index = 0;
    infile.close();

    for(int i=0; i<integers.size(); i++)
    {
        sum1 += integers[i];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<floating.size(); i++)
    {
        sum2 += floating[i];
    }
```

The integer output is working as expected. But the double values are not? Also, the double values start right after the integer values, so I didn't move the file pointer to some other location.

Comment: How does `data.txt` look like? And what is the expected result?

Comment: This is the simple data inside the text file: "2 7 -6 -13 78 34 -1 2.5 5.6 -8.13 "

Answer (score 8):

When you do

```
while(infile >> x)
{
    integers.push_back(x);

}
```

The loop is going to run until the result of `infile >> x` is false.  The result of `infile >> x` is the state of `infile`.  If `infile` is `good()` then it is true, otherwise false.  Once that loop gets to a point where `infile` is no longer `good()` it stops.  Since you haven't done anything to change the state of `infile` after that, when you get to

```
while(infile >> d)
{
    floating.push_back(d);

}
```

`infile` is still bad, so it's `false` and the loop is skipped.

To reset the state of `infile` you need to call `clear` to reset the error state.  That would give you

```
while(infile >> x)
{
    integers.push_back(x);

}
infile.clear();
while(infile >> d)
{
    floating.push_back(d);

}
```

This will still have issues though since `while(infile >> x)` is not going to fail until it reaches the first `.` in your double values.  That means the first double value you read in, and the last integer value will both be incorrect.  One way to fix this is to read in the file using a `std::string`, and then parse the string to figure out if it an integer or floating point value and convert accordingly.  Another option is to split up the data and have the integers in one file and the doubles in another.

Comment: The data inside the file is: 

"2 7 -6 -13 78 34 -1 2.5 5.6 -8.13 " 

After calling infile.clear(),  it's reading 2.5 as 0.5.

Comment: @ChaoSAdm I just added to the answer to explain why that happens and gave you a couple of potential fixes

Comment: @ChaoSAdm that is because when `operator>>` is reading into an `int`, it will read `2.5` as an integer `2` and leave `.5` in the stream for the next read. The same thing can happen for `5.6` and `-8.13`, too.  `operator>>` stops reading when it encounters a character that is not part of the type being read into. A `.` character does not apply to an `int`, so that is where `operator>>` stops reading.

Answer (score 1):

Read values as a `string`and then parse it as a `float` or an `int`.

```cpp
    string s;
    while(infile >> s)
    {
        if (s.find('.') != string::npos) { // float
            floating.push_back(stof(s));
        } else {
            integers.push_back(stoi(s));
        }
    }
```

If you expect the exponent format of `float` for e.g. `1e10` to be included, you may want to handle that case as well: `(s.find('.') != string::npos) || (s.find('e') != string::npos)`.

Comment: Do note that a `.` is not required in a floating point number.  `1e10` is a valid floating pointer number for instance.

Comment: Good point. They can put in that condition if they expect the exponent format to be included :)

Comment: You could alternatively parse the string as an `int` first, and if that fails then parse it as a `float`. No need to check the formatting manually beforehand